# Error: missing revert data (action="estimateGas,

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, blockchain, metamask, ethers.js

I am trying to call a smart contract function deployed on the Mantle testnet. The contract details are as follows:

**Contract Address**: `0xb1DC2063345F6d210AC1f9c9da2aB8131A53b938`

**ABI**:

```js
[
    {
      inputs: [
        {
          internalType: "address",
          name: "_treasury",
          type: "address",
        },
        {
          internalType: "address",
          name: "_token",
          type: "address",
        },
      ],
      stateMutability: "nonpayable",
      type: "constructor",
    },
    {
      anonymous: false,
      inputs: [
        {
          indexed: true,
          internalType: "address",
          name: "previousOwner",
          type: "address",
        },
        {
          indexed: true,
          internalType: "address",
          name: "newOwner",
          type: "address",
        },
      ],
      name: "OwnershipTransferred",
      type: "event",
    },
    {
      anonymous: false,
      inputs: [
        {
          indexed: true,
          internalType: "address",
          name: "buyer",
          type: "address",
        },
        {
          indexed: true,
          internalType: "uint256",
          name: "coord",
          type: "uint256",
        },
        {
          indexed: false,
          internalType: "uint256",
          name: "price",
          type: "uint256",
        },
        {
          indexed: false,
          internalType: "uint256",
          name: "purchaseCount",
          type: "uint256",
        },
      ],
      name: "PlotPurchase",
      type: "event",
    },
    {
      inputs: [
        {
          internalType: "uint256",
          name: "coord",
          type: "uint256",
        },
      ],
      name: "buyPlot",
      outputs: [],
      stateMutability: "payable",
      type: "function",
    },
    {
      inputs: [
        {
          internalType: "uint256",
          name: "startCoord",
          type: "uint256",
        },
        {
          internalType: "uint256",
          name: "endCoord",
          type: "uint256",
        },
      ],
      name: "getAllOwners",
      outputs: [
        {
          internalType: "address[]",
          name: "",
          type: "address[]",
        },
      ],
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function",
    },
    {
      inputs: [
        {
          internalType: "uint256",
          name: "startCoord",
          type: "uint256",
        },
        {
          internalType: "uint256",
          name: "endCoord",
          type: "uint256",
        },
      ],
      name: "getAllPurchaseCounts",
      outputs: [
        {
          internalType: "uint256[]",
          name: "",
          type: "uint256[]",
        },
      ],
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function",
    },
    {
      inputs: [],
      name: "getOwnerCount",
      outputs: [
        {
          internalType: "uint256",
          name: "",
          type: "uint256",
        },
      ],
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function",
    },
    {
      inputs: [],
      name: "mintPerPlot",
      outputs: [
        {
          internalType: "uint256",
          name: "",
          type: "uint256",
        },
      ],
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function",
    },
    {
      inputs: [],
      name: "owner",
      outputs: [
        {
          internalType: "address",
          name: "",
          type: "address",
        },
      ],
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function",
    },
    {
      inputs: [
        {
          internalType: "address",
          name: "",
          type: "address",
        },
      ],
      name: "plotsOwned",
      outputs: [
        {
          internalType: "uint256",
          name: "",
          type: "uint256",
        },
      ],
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function",
    },
    {
      inputs: [
        {
          internalType: "uint256",
          name: "coord",
          type: "uint256",
        },
      ],
      name: "price",
      outputs: [
        {
          internalType: "uint256",
          name: "",
          type: "uint256",
        },
      ],
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function",
    },
    {
      inputs: [],
      name: "renounceOwnership",
      outputs: [],
      stateMutability: "nonpayable",
      type: "function",
    },
    {
      inputs: [],
      name: "token",
      outputs: [
        {
          internalType: "contract IERC20",
          name: "",
          type: "address",
        },
      ],
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function",
    },
    {
      inputs: [
        {
          internalType: "address",
          name: "newOwner",
          type: "address",
        },
      ],
      name: "transferOwnership",
      outputs: [],
      stateMutability: "nonpayable",
      type: "function",
    },
    {
      inputs: [],
      name: "treasury",
      outputs: [
        {
          internalType: "address",
          name: "",
          type: "address",
        },
      ],
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function",
    },
    {
      inputs: [
        {
          internalType: "address",
          name: "tokenAddress",
          type: "address",
        },
        {
          internalType: "uint256",
          name: "amount",
          type: "uint256",
        },
      ],
      name: "withdrawTokens",
      outputs: [],
      stateMutability: "nonpayable",
      type: "function",
    },
    {
      stateMutability: "payable",
      type: "receive",
    },
  ]
```

**Function implementation 1**:

```js
const buyPixel = async (row: number, col: number) => {
  const { gridContract: contract } = getEthers();
  try {
    const row1 = BigInt(123);
    await contract.buyPlot(row1);
    // const column1 = BigInt(c);
    // let r = ethers.parseUnits(row.toString(), 0);
    // let c = ethers.parseUnits(col.toString(), 0);
    // const basePrice = ethers.parseEther("0.1"); // Set the base price in Ether
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error buying pixel:", err);
  }
}
```

**Error Message 1**:

```
Error: missing revert data (action="estimateGas", data=null, reason=null, transaction={ "data": "0x7b1949d2000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007b", "from": "0x64627c96aB9d0a24B8bAA3F53336cbb39Bc6A55a", "to": "0xb1DC2063345F6d210AC1f9c9da2aB8131A53b938" }, invocation=null, revert=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=6.6.7)
```

**Function implementation 2**:

```js
const buyPixel = async (row: number, col: number) => {
  const { gridContract: contract } = getEthers();
  let r = ethers.parseUnits(row.toString(), 0);
  let c = ethers.parseUnits(col.toString(), 0);
  const pxCount = await contract.owner();
  console.log(contract, row, col, r, c, pxCount, "pb");
  try {
    const row1 = BigInt(r);
    const column1 = BigInt(c);
    const basePrice = ethers.parseEther("0.1"); // Set the base price in Ether
    const plotPrice = basePrice * column1 * row1;
    // Send the transaction with the correct amount of Ether (in Wei)
    const overrides = {
      value: ethers.parseUnits(plotPrice + "", 18),
    };
    const result = await contract.buyPlot(row1, column1, overrides);
    console.log(result, "res");
    // Transaction successful, update pixel state
    // setPixels((prevPixels) => {
    //   const updatedPixels = [...prevPixels];
    //   updatedPixels[row][col] = true;
    //   return updatedPixels;
    // });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error buying pixel:", err);
  }
}
```

**Error Message 2**:

```
Error: no matching fragment (operation="fragment", info={ "args": [ 1, 1, { "value": 100000000000000000000000000000000000 } ], "key": "buyPlot" }, code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=6.6.7)
```

**buyPlot**

````
function buyPlot(uint256 coord) external payable isValidCoord(coord) {
     Plot storage plot = grid[coord];
     uint256 plotPrice = BASE_PRICE << plot.purchaseCount;

     require(msg.value >= plotPrice, "Not enough ETH sent to buy plot");

     if (msg.value > plotPrice) {
         payable(msg.sender).transfer(msg.value - plotPrice);
     }

     address currentOwner = plot.owner;

     // Ensure the sender is not the contract itself
     require(msg.sender != address(this), "Contract cannot buy plots");

     // protocol takes 25% of the purchase price
     // 75% goes to the previous owner
     // if there is no previous owner, 100% goes to the protocol
     // the protocol is the owner of all plots at the start
     if (currentOwner != address(0)) {
         uint256 transferAmount = plotPrice.mul(3) / 4;

         // Ensure the transfer to the current owner is successful
         require(payable(currentOwner).send(transferAmount), "Transfer to current owner failed");

         if (currentOwner != msg.sender) {
             plotsOwned[currentOwner] -= 1;
             plotsOwned[msg.sender] += 1;
             plot.owner = msg.sender;
         }
     } else {
         plot.owner = msg.sender;
         plotsOwned[msg.sender] += 1;
     }

     // Transfer the purchase price to the contract owner
     if (address(this).balance > 0) {
         require(payable(treasury).send(address(this).balance), "Transfer to treasury failed");
     }
     plot.purchaseCount += 1;

     // mint tokens for the buyer
     token.safeTransfer(msg.sender, mintPerPlot);

     emit PlotPurchase(msg.sender, coord, plotPrice, plot.purchaseCount);
 }```

I have verified that the ABI and the contract address are correct as deployed on the Mantle testnet. However, I'm encountering issues with both implementations when trying to call the `buyPlot` function. Any help in resolving these errors would be greatly appreciated.
````

Comment: There may be an error in the implementation of the buyPlot method

Comment: @MadJackal I have added the buyPlot function also, pls check

Comment: In the first implementation, you call the method buyPlot without passing value, but the method uses the control construct require(msg.value >= plotPrice, "Not enough ETH sent to buy plot"), which causes the transaction to be rolled back

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error while using newer versions of [solc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/solc).

To fix:

1. `yarn remove solc`
2. `yarn add solc@0.8.7-fixed`
3. Compile your contract and redeploy

Answer (score 0):

use a fixed version of solc. Something like 0.8.7-fixed or 0.8.14-fixed.

```json
"dependencies": {
    "solc": "^0.8.14-fixed"
}
```